# How to debug and what is the meaning of Hunk #1 FAILED at 34. Hunk #2 FAILED at 56. Hunk #3 FAILED at 113?

Tags: patches, magento1.9.2.4, supee-8788v2

I am applying patch `SUPEE-8788` and get below error

```
PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v2-2016-10-14-09-42-47.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design/Images.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design.phtml
checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
checking file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
Hunk #1 FAILED at 34.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 56.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 113.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
```

I want to know what is the meaning of `Hunk #1 FAILED` and how can i debug for it?

[EDIT]

I found that js file(`js/mage/adminhtml/product.js`) was minify so its give me error but i am not sure how to debug it properly. Now patch applied successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It's look like you have not installed the previous versions of SUPEE patches.
You can check SUPEE patches status here  [magereport](http://www.magereport.com/).

Please apply all previous versions and then install SUPEE-8788.

[For read about hunk click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14282775)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i have installed previous patches. problem was due to minify js file. i have update question with edit.